# Не могу понять почему происходит ошибка в поле времени(time)?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

Постоянно выдает ошибку в поле с временем

> Error parsing column 11(my_time=08:00:00 - Object)

Если убрать поле времени (my_time) или если его перевести в string тогда ошибок нету. 
Думаю не правильно указываю формат даты в модели?
Где делаю не так?

Работаю ASP.NET Core 3.1 + PostgreSQL + Dapper

Таблица в БД:

```
id bigserial
my_time time without time zone
```

Модель:

```
public int id {get;set;}
public DateTime my_time {get;set;}
```

Repository

```
public async Task<ExamShedules> FindExamId(int id_predmet)
        {
           using(IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                return (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<ExamShedules>("SELECT * FROM tester.exam_schedules WHERE id=@id", new { id=id})).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было указать тип данных TimeSpan в модели